# Subclasses of singleton not working together

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, class, singleton

I use this code to create subclasses which are individually singletons:

```
+(id)sharedManager {

    Class class = [self class];

    static SPPanelManager *sharedManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedManager = [[class alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedManager;
}
```

And then in the .h of each subclass, there's this, with the name of the class as the return value:

```
+(SPWeatherManager *)sharedManager;
```

If these are used individually, they work perfectly, and launch their class as expected. If used together however, they all take the class of the first singleton generated.

How could i change this code so that the subclasses are all their own singletons?

Comment: What sense does it make to have singletons of subclasses? (sharedManager is not a full-fledged singleton, but if we ignore that difference ...) The return value `[SPWeatherManager sharedManager]` is also an instance of SPPanelManager, so why should   `[SPPanelManager sharedManager]` return a different object?

Comment: Here, `[self class]` (and `class`) is the same as `self`

Comment: There will only be one set of statics, unless you re-implement sharedManager in each subclass.  Hence only one singleton.  (But since you should rarely ever need more than one singleton in an app, this should not be a problem -- if you feel the need for a bunch of singletons you're doing something wrong.)

Answer (score 2):

It seems your complicated construct did not confuse dispatch_once a bit.
As requested (that's what dispatch_once is for, after all), sharedManager is only assigned once.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create multiple singletons. Change the class factory method to test for the class, and if the base class create/return one object, and if the subclass another. You need two dispatch once objects (typing this on an iPad, could do real code later). In a more general sense, you could use a mutable dictionary to hold the dispatch object and singleton, thus supporting a virtually unlimited number of subclasses, by getting the NSString name of the class and using it as the key.